# Javascript sort with function not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone

When calling sort(function) in Javascript on an iPhone it doesn't seem to sort. 
For example:

```
devices.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.name > b.name;
                });
```

Are there some known limitations or can someone help me how to do this on an iPhone. It seems to work fine in Chrome, IE, Firefox.

Comment: Does it work in Safari on Windows and/or Mac OS?

Answer (score 9):

Your comparison function is broken: It should return a numerical value which has to be negative if `a < b`, zero if `a = b` and positive if `a > b`, ie

```
function(a, b) {
    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Your function returns `false` if `a.name < b.name`, which will be converted to `0` and therefore means the values should be regarded as equal. It shouldn't work at all, but if it does, this is by coincidence (ie depends on the sorting algorithm and/or input set).

Answer (score 0):

The sort function needs to return -1, 0, or 1.

```
devices.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.name == b.name) {
    return 0; // ambiguous
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, check out this binarySearch that allows you to quickly find items in large sorted lists using a custom comparator function.

http://www.dweebd.com/javascript/binary-search-an-array-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly return -1, 0 or 1, as per the definition of this function I guess. My bad.

```
                    devices.sort(function(a, b) {
                    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
                    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
                    return 0;
                });
```

Works now.